# JAXB marshal namespace prefix

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws, marshalling

I'm developing a client to consume a web service, but for some reason my requests are not properly processed unless all namespaces are correct and without any prefix.

All my classes were created using the provide XSD's and WSDL's by the service provider.

**NfeDadosMsg.class**

```
package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.wsdl.nfestatusservico4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "nfeDadosMsg")
public class NfeDadosMsg {

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

}
```

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeStatusServico4", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe.wsdl.nfestatusservico4;
```

**TConsStatServ.class**
    package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "TConsStatServ",
    propOrder = {"tpAmb", "cuf", "xServ"}
)
public class TConsStatServ {
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    protected String tpAmb;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "cUF",
        required = true
    )
    protected String cuf;
    @XmlElement(
        required = true
    )
    protected String xServ;
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "versao",
        required = true
    )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String versao;

    public TConsStatServ() {
    }

    ...

}
```

package-info.java

```
package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe;

@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package br.inf.portalfiscal.nfe
```

Output xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <S:Body>
    <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeStatusServico4" xmlns:ns2="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
      <ns2:consStatServ versao="4.00">
        <ns2:tpAmb>2</ns2:tpAmb>
        <ns2:cUF>33</ns2:cUF>
        <ns2:xServ>STATUS</ns2:xServ>
      </ns2:consStatServ>
    </nfeDadosMsg>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

For some reason the web service doesn't consumes it correctly if I have a prefixed namespace. So what I need

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <S:Body>
    <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeStatusServico4">
      <consStatServ versao="4.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <cUF>33</cUF>
        <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
      </consStatServ>
    </nfeDadosMsg>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

How can I change the namespace on the output xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by replacing

```
@XmlMixed
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected List<Object> content;
```

With the expected entity

```
@XmlElement(namespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
protected TRetEnviNfe;
```